# ServiceStack pre-packaged User Interface elements

Tags: servicestack

I've developed a number of services with ServiceStack, some of them have UI requirements which are needed to configure them. I can ship the background REST services easily enough in a DLL and get them registered in the hosting application just by adding the dll  to a list of DLL's to be scanned.

But what I'm wondering about is the UI elements, what is the best way to ship these for a service stack user interface? They basically rely on a _Layout.cshtml being available and after that they are standalone. I obviously don't want to mess up an existing site, or clash with that sites own page names or routes.

Does anyone have any previous experience doing something like this with Service Stack. Is there a neat way to perform this kind of integration with it's architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the different [Web UI + Razor projects in RazorRockstars](https://github.com/ServiceStack/RazorRockstars/tree/master/src), basically if you're using a self-host you can set the **build action** to be **Content** and set the Copy option to **Copy if Newer** in which case VS.NET will copy the Razor Views to the `bin/` output folder which you can xcopy and deploy as-is.

If it's just a standard ASP.NET application then you would just copy the Razor files with as part of your xcopy and deployment script.

There is also a Embedded Resources option where you could embed the Razor Views in the compiled ASP.NET dll as seen in [RazorRockstars.Console](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console) test project, but it uses an external non-Open Source library feature to enable this.